# NioEndpoint - Incorrect connection count, multiple calls to socket.close for the same socket

Tags: spring-webflux

I have created a Spring Webflux application with tomcat as an embedded server. Service is working fine, but in the server logs I can see a lot of warm messages "[http-nio-8080-exec-9] NioEndpoint - Incorrect connection count, multiple calls to socket.close for the same socket."
I am running the tomcat with the default configuration.
Please help.

Pom dependency

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
    <artifactId>reactor-bom</artifactId>
    <version>Californium-SR8</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
```